# Wilcoxon Rank Sum test - appropriate to compare frequency of events between two sources?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have some data on the frequency that a particular claim is referenced by two distinct types of sources. The first is traditional news media, and the second source are conspiracy theory sites. I want to test the hypothesis that conspiracy sites more frequency cite a given claim than conventional mainstream media sites.

I have data for (a) how many times the claim was cited in 83 news sources, given below

```
news = [1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   7   1   1   1   6   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   5   1   1   4   1   1];
```

and for how often the same claim was cited in 17 conspiracy theory sources:

```
ct = [1 2 1 6 2 20  1 1 1 2 9 1 4 2 2 7 7]
```

I do not a prior have any reason to believe this data will be normally distributed nor am I interested in means, so my understanding is that a non-parametric test ought to be employed. From my initial reading, I think the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test might be appropriate to test this hypothesis, and that I should use a right tailed version because I have a specific direction I wish to test in the hypothesis. Deploying this in MATLAB I get

```
[p,h,stats] = ranksum(ct,news,'tail','right');
```

which yields $p = 3.5166 \times 10^{-6}$ and strong rejection of the null that they're from populations with the same median. But is this the right test to employ, or would another non-parametric method be better for analysing data of this sort? I will in future have to run similar analysis, so am open to suggestion or correction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data: (You might want to check whether I captured your
data correctly.)

```
news = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,
  1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,
  1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,
  1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,   
  2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,4,1,1)

ct = c(1,2,1,6,2,20,1,1,1,2,9,1,4,2,2,7,7)
```

Data summaries:

```
summary(news)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.341   1.000   7.000 
table(news)
news
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
69  8  1  1  1  1  1 

summary(ct)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   2.000   4.059   6.000  20.000 
table(ct)
ct
 1  2  4  6  7  9 20 
 6  5  1  1  2  1  1
```

From boxplots (News at bottom), there seems little doubt that the
claim was cited more frequently by CT sources. But
maybe CT sources, cite all their claims more heavily as a matter of style, so
it is not clear in what sense the two samples are comparable.

```
boxplot(news, ct, horizontal=T, pch=19, col="skyblue")
```

[image]

Also, the two sample distributions, both right skewed,
are of remarkably different shapes, so the **Wilcoxon
Rank Sum** test cannot be interpreted as a straightforward
comparison of sample medians.

Using the implementation of this Wilcoxon test in R, I
get results similar to yours, for the one-sided test.
For smaller sample sizes than yours, the Wilcoxon SR test
does not always give reliable P-values in the presence
of as many ties as in your data. However, there is no
warning message for your data.

```
wilcox.test(news, ct, alt="less")

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  news and ct
W = 336, p-value = 4.139e-06
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is less than 0
```

In such cases, one does not directly compare medians,
but tests whether one sample (in your case CT) stochastically dominates the other.

The empirical CDF (ECDF) of a sample is made by
sorting the data, starting with 0 at the left and
making an upward jump of $1/n$ at each observed value,
reaching height $1$ at the right.
(If there are ties of multiplicity $k$ at a value,
then the jump is of size $k/n.)$

A dominant sample plots to the right of a non-dominant one, and thus the dominant ECDF plots below the other ECDF.
Here, the ECDT for CT (brown) plots consistently below the ECDF (blue).

```
plot(ecdf(ct), col="brown")
 plot(ecdf(news), add=T, col="blue")
```

[image]
for News.

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful! Is there a condition that the two samples should have broadly similar shapes for the RS test or is does it simply mean that it's not a straightforward median difference issue?

Comment: The Wilcoxon Rank Sum test (also called Mann-Whitney Wilcoxon test) can be considered a test of different population medians only if the two samples are of similar shapes and variances. Otherwise, it is a test of stochastic dominance (whether values in one dist'n tend to be larger than in the other)--which is a somewhat broader concept. (Looking at a comparison of ECDF plots as at the end of by Answer is an easy way to judge this.) 
This [article](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00031305.2017.1305291) from _The American Statistician_ may be helpful.